# Inequality of fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Rudin book's, page 101, chapter 5. 
[image]

**My question is:** why does the inequality holds in $\text{(6)}$?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just estimate:
$$\begin{align*}
||\Lambda_{n}||&=\sup_{\{f:||f||_{\infty}=1\}}|\Lambda_{n}f|\\
&=\sup_{\{f:||f||_{\infty}=1\}}\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)D_{n}(-t)\;dt\right|\\
&\leq\sup_{\{f:||f||_{\infty}=1\}}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(-t)||D_{n}(t)|\;dt\\
&\leq\sup_{\{f:||f||_{\infty}=1\}}||f||_{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|D_{n}(t)|\;dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|D_{n}(t)|\;dt\\
&=||D_{n}||_{1}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Oh Taylor Martin, thank you.